# Random odd numbers between range with the exception of a single number in C

Tags: c, random, numbers

Here is my code:

```
alpha = ((rand() % 12) + 1) * 2 + 1;
```

I want to generate random **odd** numbers between 0-25. But except integer **13**. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: generate and check, if 13, regenerate.

Comment: also containing 25 or is 23 the last one you want? between 0-25 is kinda oddly phrased...

Comment: actually gcd(alpha,26)=1 this is why 13 should not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generates number from 0 to 23. If it's a 13, then store 25 in your variable :

```
alpha = ((rand() % 11) + 1) * 2 + 1;
if (alpha == 13) alpha = 25;
```

Comment: it works correctly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple loop to retry the operation if alpha gets 13 :

```
  int alpha = 13;
  while (alpha == 13)
    alpha = ((rand() % 12) + 1) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: (Psst. I suggest you delete this answer before anyone else notices it.)

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Oh, mistake from me, used "!=" instead of "==". I'll fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int universe[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, /* ... omit 13 ... */ 25};
int index = randto(sizeof universe / sizeof *universe);
alpha = universe[index];
```

Where `randto(n)` returns a random number from `0` up to and excluding `n`.